# Python 3.8 requests get always returns first page

Tags: python, python-requests

Stackoverflow!
I am trying to parse this website: *https://www.ligloo.fr/annonce-immobiliere/studio.html* and using this url to navigate pages: *https://www.ligloo.fr/annonce-immobiliere/STUDIO.html#!/?page=page_number&tri=pertinance

Here is what i'm currently running but every iteration i get the same html tree

```
def main():
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'
session = requests.session()
session.headers.update({'user_agent':user_agent})
initial_url = 'https://www.ligloo.fr/annonce-immobiliere/{0}.html#!/?page={1}&tri=pertinance'
categories = ('STUDIO', 'LOFTS', 'MAISON', 'APPART-2-PIECES-MOINS-DE-40-M2')
for category in categories:
    dictionary_of_links = {}
    for page in range(1, 6):
        url = initial_url.format(category, page)
        result = session.get(url)
        tree = html.fromstring(result.text) #why tree is the same every time?
```

EDIT: Thank you all who tried to help me! I found out that actually .html file doesn't change when navigating through site so using selenium is the only option i could think of now

Comment: Hmm.. so `requests.session` has been deprecated in 1.0.0. Also, is there a reason why you're not using `requests.get`?

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is not encoding the special characters I think - try changing

```
?page={1}
```

to

```
?page%3D{1}
```

Comment: I think you're right. Alternatively using `requests.get` with `params` can avoid this issue.

Comment: I printed out url and it seemed to be right. Also i changed to "?page%3D{1}" and nothing changed. Please, show me how to add params to this url

Comment: I didn't test this but my answer below may help.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.6+

```
initial_url = 'https://www.ligloo.fr/annonce-immobiliere'
categories = ('STUDIO', 'LOFTS', 'MAISON', 'APPART-2-PIECES-MOINS-DE-40-M2')

for category in categories:
    url = f"{initial_url}/{category}.html"
    for page in range(1, 6):
        params = {'page': page, 'tri': 'pertinance'}
        result = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

Comment: Now it return other page, not the one i needed, maybe i should add '#!' after '.html'? EDIT: I see: it must be {category} not {categories}. Let me test it

Comment: Well. It works but gives me the same page every time

Comment: Yes, a typo. This is just a template for how to do it with `requests.get` and `params` input. Feel free to modify.

Comment: I think this is an issue with site navigation. I went to it and click on page 2 and I get this page: https://www.ligloo.fr/annonce-immobiliere/STUDIO.html&page=1#!/annonce-immobiliere/STUDIO.html%3Fpage%3D2%26tri%3Dpertinance

Comment: So the issue is how the site handles pagination I think.

Comment: What about this link: https://www.ligloo.fr/annonce-immobiliere/STUDIO.html#!/annonce-immobiliere/STUDIO.html%3Fpage%3D4%26tri%3Dpertinance? Is there a way in requests to change '3D4' parameter? It perfectly lands on page after '3D'. I tried formatting it but failed.

Comment: My code block won't work because it' assuming that `url` is the same for pagination. You would have to have two separate ones for `page==1` vs `page > 1`

Comment: Will this formatting even work? `f"https://www.ligloo.fr/annonce-immobiliere/STUDIO.html#!/annonce-immobiliere/STUDIO.html%3Fpage%3D{page}%26tri%3Dpertinance"`
Honestly, i tried that before but even page > 1 returned me first page. I'm stuck on this error for more that hour